# ItemsControl displaying class name

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

This app is displaying the class name of a collection instead of a text-box as desired. I've read other issues with this, but cannot figure out what I'm missing. I have a datacontext, I'm bound to the collection as an itemsource, and I've added a single item.  All I want is to bind the collection 'Boxes' in my view model 'DrawBoxViewModel' to an item source, and have it display a single item as a text box.  All help is appreciated.

First my XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="BoxMaker2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:BoxMaker2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:vm="using:BoxMaker2.ViewModels"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>
    <vm:DrawBoxViewModel x:Key="DrawBoxViewModel"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Canvas DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource DrawBoxViewModel}}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Boxes}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas Width="350" Height="600" Background="AliceBlue"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="vm:Box" x:Key="test">
                <VariableSizedWrapGrid>
                    <TextBox Background="White" 
                             Text="{x:Bind Data}"
                             Width="100"
                             Height="100"/>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid.RenderTransform>
                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding LeftCanvas}" Y="{Binding TopCanvas}"/>
                    </VariableSizedWrapGrid.RenderTransform>
                </VariableSizedWrapGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Resources>
    </ItemsControl>
</Canvas>
```

And now my viewmodel:

```
namespace BoxMaker2.ViewModels
{
public class DrawBoxViewModel
{
    #region fields

    private ObservableCollection<Box> _boxes;

    #endregion

    #region properties

    public ObservableCollection<Box> Boxes { get { return this._boxes; } }

    #endregion

    #region constructors

    public DrawBoxViewModel()
    {
        this._boxes = new ObservableCollection<Box>();
        _boxes.Add(new Box() { Data = "hello!", LeftCanvas = 200, TopCanvas = 200 });
    }

    #endregion

}

public class Box : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _generation;
    public int Generation
    {
        get { return _generation; }
        set { _generation = value; OnPropertyChanged("Generation"); }
    }

    private int _childNo;
    public int ChildNo
    {
        get { return _childNo; }
        set { _childNo = value; OnPropertyChanged("ChildNo"); }
    }

    private Box _parentBox;
    public Box ParentBox
    {
        get { return _parentBox; }
        set { _parentBox = value; OnPropertyChanged("ParentBox"); }
    }

    private List<Box> _childrenBox;
    public List<Box> ChildrenBox
    {
        get { return _childrenBox; }
        set { _childrenBox = value; OnPropertyChanged("ChildrenBox"); }
    }

    private string _data;
    public string Data
    {
        get { return _data; }
        set
        {
            _data = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }

    private double _topCanvas;
    public double TopCanvas
    {
        get { return _topCanvas; }
        set
        {
            _topCanvas = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TopCanvas");
        }
    }

    private double _leftCanvas;
    public double LeftCanvas
    {
        get { return _leftCanvas; }
        set
        {
            _leftCanvas = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LeftCanvas");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve but here's a few issues I have found in your code.

1. You should assign your VM to the `DataContext` of the `Page`
   directly.

   ```
   <Page.DataContext>
       <vm:DrawBoxViewModel />
   </Page.DataContext>
   ```

   After doing so, you can now *remove* `DataContext="{Binding
   Source={StaticResource DrawBoxViewModel}}"` from your `Canvas`.
2. Replace `<ItemsControl.Resource>` with
   `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>` and remove `x:Key="test"`, assuming you want to show multiple
   `TextBox`es on the UI. The `DataTemplate` within the `Resource` you
   defined won't do anything until you reference it by its key. I don't
   think you really want that here though.
3. You should use `x:Bind` for your `X` & `Y` binding

   ```
   <TranslateTransform X="{x:Bind LeftCanvas}"
                       Y="{x:Bind TopCanvas}" />
   ```
4. Your `Boxes` collection can be simplified as following

   ```
   #region properties

   public ObservableCollection<Box> Boxes { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Box>();

   #endregion

   #region constructors

   public DrawBoxViewModel()
   {
       Boxes.Add(new Box() { Data = "hello!", LeftCanvas = 0, TopCanvas = 200 });
   }

   #endregion
   ```

Hope this helps!

Comment: 0.The OP didn't ask what is the right way to implement MVVM. He asked how to display the elements in the collection properly. 1. The view model is perfectly fine as a resource. He is referencing it via StaticResource so that's fine. 
2 He doesn't have to x:Bind anything. That's a user preference. 3. You need to explain why copying WPF code doesn't work on UWP. Obviously he's looking up WPF tutorials that don't apply to UWP and it's obvious that he's a rookie.

Comment: @bleepzter you should *always* you set the DataContext at the top level and let it flow down. This is best practice. When you have x:Bind all set up to have the performance gain, and you are already doing so for your Data property, what's the reason to skip those two?

Comment: You work on assumptions. So first - what if the page has something else that sets the data context, perhaps in code behind or some other way? So stop making assumptions. It is a best practice but it is better to suggest it as best practice and explain why. Do not just order the OP what they should or should do.

Second x:Bind is compiled which is good for speed, but it's also limiting in comparison to regular bindings. They are more adequate in certain scenarios that x:Bind can't handle. So once again "should" is not an operative word - "suggest" is more like it, and explain why.

Comment: @bleepzter both of these solved my problem.  I ended up using Justin XL solution because I considered it simpler, it was a definite mistake to have the datatemplate defined in resources instead of itemtemplate.  Thank you both for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Your Items control doesn't know which data template to use. Currently your view model has a template associated to it via the `x:DataType="vm:Box"` which is defined as a resource in the items control.

The problem is that Universal Windows Platform doesn't recognize templates associated to data types. So even though there is a template, the control doesn't know how to find it when it is rendering the collection of view models.

Automatic resolving of templates based on bound types was a function of WPF which is not available in UWP.

What that means is that in WPF you could associate a data template to a class/object via the `x:DataType="Object Type"` attribute of the data template (which is what you did). When the collection is bound, the rendering engine would auto-magically match the the individual items in the collection to their respective templates.

This was very powerful because if your collection had many different types of boxes for example (or things inheriting from DrawBoxViewModel) you could render each item type differently by simply defining a template. Well this is no more. Microsoft destroyed that feature in UWP.

So long story short - move the template to the page resource collection. Give it a key such as:

```
<Page.Resources>
   <vm:DrawBoxViewModel x:Key="DrawBoxViewModel"/>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="test">
      <VariableSizedWrapGrid>
          <TextBox Background="White" 
              Text="{x:Bind Data}"
              Width="100"
              Height="100"/>
             <VariableSizedWrapGrid.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="{Binding LeftCanvas}" Y="{Binding TopCanvas}"/>
             </VariableSizedWrapGrid.RenderTransform>
        </VariableSizedWrapGrid>
     </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
```

Reference the template in your items control as follows: 
`<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Boxes} ItemTemplate={StaticResource test} ">`

Comment: But not for automatic resolve of templates as in WPF.

Comment: Yeah but it's used as WPF.

Comment: No it's NOT. It serves completely different purposes in UWP.